# View with gesture listener and onLongClickListener

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I'm trying to implement a view that has both a longClickListener and a gesture dectector. Basically, I need a button to show a view when the user long clicks on the first view, and then I want to dectect a fling motion up. I would like to make it so that the user does not have to lift their finger at all, and hit both the longclick, and the fling motion.

Here is my code for the longClickListener:

```
flipCard.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    answerRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    answerRight.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.grow_from_middle));
                    answerWrong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    answerWrong.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.grow_from_middle));
                    return false;
           }
        });
```

Here is the code for my gesture dector:

```
gestureDetectorScore = new GestureDetector(new ScoreGestureDetector());
    gestureListenerScore = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetectorScore.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
private class ScoreGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 5;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 2;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
         try {
              //if (Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                 //return false;
              // right to left swipe
              //if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
              if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){ 
                 Toast.makeText(AndroidOrientationSensor.this, "Up Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }  
              //else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
              else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                   Toast.makeText(AndroidOrientationSensor.this, "Down Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e1){
        Toast.makeText(AndroidOrientationSensor.this, "Up Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Finally, I am setting the gesture dectector to the the "flipCard" view like this:

```
flipCard.setOnTouchListener(gestureListenerScore);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to solve this problem is placing a gestureDectector on the view and overriding the onDown method. This allowed me to simulate a click event. I was unable to get both a long click and a swipe event, but for my purposes the click event triggers during the swipe which seems to work well enough. Thanks to GauntFace for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're going to have is if the touch event is consumed by the button, then the second view won't receive it.

Even if it did, the fling I imagine will only get called when the user performs a fling from start to finish.

The only thing I can think of doing (despite it being very horrible / hacky) is to try and inset a fake up touch event. This might then allow the user to perform the fling, but this isn't particularly stable either.

Better way to handle it would be to have a view group consume the touch events, pass the touch events to a gesture detector to detect a long click, then set a flag within the view groups touch listener to indicate a fling is expected, then manually detect when prev y and current y go beyond a threshold. This will give you some idea of velocity but probably no where near as meaningful as the velocity provided in the onFling callback method.

Comment: Good idea, I'm having a lot of trouble implementing this though. I'm trying to recreate a longClickEvent within the gesture listener. By checking the coordinates to make sure they match with the button, and then simulating a long click, I may be able to catch the fling event.

Comment: Unfortunately because you want it to all occur in a single touch event there is not going to be an easy way to do this. All I can say is from your current code, rather than pass the GestureDetector into the setOnTouchListener, you can override the onTouchEvent method, then go return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent); obviously with this, after a long click you can consumer the touchevents yourself and do what you want with them (i.e. detect a custom fling)

Answer (score 0):

The GestureListener also has a onLongPress event.

Comment: Thats true, but then the event is consumed, and doesn't catch the fling event. Its actually pretty interesting, as in order to catch an onLongPress event, you should first catch the onDown event. The api states that "All other events should be preceded by this". Futhermore, the onLongPress events always consume the event, which would negate the fling event. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onLongPress(android.view.MotionEvent)